# how to model (mvc) an abstract time period for employe shift management

Tags: sql, model-view-controller, time, icalendar, overlapping

*I've started thinking about an employee shift management application to handle the shifts (who works when, trading, etc) at my current workplace (that uses pen and paper and hasn't got anyway for us employees to communicate about changes without going through the boss and be on site).*

Currently the shifts are modeled loosely as:

- There is a recurring 4 week period (from Monday week 1 to Sunday week 4)
- There is a template for placing employees in this 4 week period
- Every 4 months (ie 3 times a year) the 4 week template is projected over the next 4 month period

*The shifts have been the same for a long time and it seems many employees would prefer to have them changed (I can say this by the requests for change that come in every time a new 4 month is set).*

What I'm aiming at are the models:

- Shift_group_tpl (the 4 week period above)
- Shift_tpl (a single shift in the 4 week period, including info on who defaults to work this shift)
- Shift_group (a set period of time whit actual shifts)
- Shift (a set shift whit a real time period and an employee - and the possibility to be changed both in start_time, end_time and employee)

I've thought of a way to do this with recurring iCalendar events: Creating RRULE's (without an endtime) and then calculate (using temporary start and end times) if that specific Shift_group_tpl could be used within a real Shift_group. (The problem with this approach is that I can't figure out how to trim the Shift_group_tpl's to fit into the start or end of a Shift_group.)

What I'm looking for are some other perspectives or ways of doing it or even just a pat on the shoulder letting me know that I'm on the right track (and then giving advice on the trimming problem).

/iole1

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm aiming at are the models:
>
> Shift_group_tpl (the 4 week period above)
> Shift_tpl (a single shift in the 4 week period, including info on who defaults to work this shift)
> Shift_group (a set period of time whit actual shifts)
> Shift (a set shift whit a real time period and an employee - and the possibility to be changed both in start_time, end_time and employee)

You have "sql" as a tag for this post? So im guessing you want these as SQL tables?

By the sounds, the problem is that your considering the data you have, rather than the abstract concepts you need to store that data. Which is what you'd need to do to create an application. (Most likely a "Shifts" table, rather than the four tables above).

There is little information here to help, Consider refining your thoughts and ask another question.